# ReST API and order of entities in the URI

Tags: rest, uri

ReST API and order of entities in the URI

UC 1:

Get a list of services performed for the given customerId in the past 60 0r 90... or 365 days.

How to define the uri; Which entity should be specified first in the uri, Customer or ContactInfo?

```
www.example.com/operations/customers/{CustomerId}/services?noOfDaysInPast=60
www.example.com/operations/services/customers/{customerId}?noOfDaysInPast=60
www.example.com/operations/services/{customerId}?noOfDaysInPast=60
www.example.com/operations/services/?customerId=12345&noOfDaysInPast=60
```

UC 2:

Get the contact info for a given customerid (contantInfo = name + Service Address)

How to define the uri 
Which entity should be specified first in the uri, Customer or ContactInfo?

```
www.example.com/operations/customers/{CustomerId}/contactInfo?addressType=SERVICE
www.example.com/operations/contactInfo/customers/{customerId}?addressType=SERVICE
```

Answer (score 0):

> Get a list of services performed for the given customerId in the past 60 0r 90... or 365 days.

Let's look at this in steps:

> Get a list of services

```
www.example.com/operations/services
```

> performed for the given customerId

```
www.example.com/operations/services/?customerId=12345
```

> in the past 60 days

```
www.example.com/operations/services/?customerId=12345&noOfDaysInPast=60
```

There you go.